# How to determine a user logout in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, usersession

I have to maintain the user login and logout time in database. For login its easy but for logout , if I use `Application_End ()` in `global.asax` for logging. It gives me exception.

My Code in asax file:

```
Application_End()
{
  HttpCurrent.Context.Session.Abandon();
  LogUserLogoutTimeToDatabase();
}
```

Comment: What exception does it give you? This is probably an indicator as to what the problem is.

Comment: Does logout have a specific action associated with it ? An application end probably means all your users lose their sessions, this is not the only way for a log out, i am guessing.

Comment: Something like Session is not valid for this context

Comment: @ryadavilli i want logout log for individual users. Not for all users at a time

Comment: Which is the reason why i said Application end is not the right place. Check the answers below, people have given good explanations about using a log off button and handling the session end event.

Comment: I just want to say to say log the user as logout in db if he
1. Closes his/hr browser
2. Properly logout using the logout button.
3. Or somehow he got disconnected from the server (e.g. power failure and immediate shutdowns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use Session_End().  A user can simply close their browser, and to them, they are now "logged off" - but nothing has alerted the server that they have logged off unless they clicked a "log off" button before closing their browser.  So, once their session times out, the Session_End() event will be triggered and you can capture your logout in there.

Answer (score 0):

You're best and first bet would be a logout button in the application. 
After that you can use a Session timeout event with a very short session time.

Application_End is triggered when the application is shutting down but not during a server crash.

Answer (score 0):

the best way to achieve this is , use `onClick` event of *logout button*.

when user click on log out button , store that time in `database`...